# Node.js : control flow with forEach

Tags: arrays, database, json, node.js, control-flow

I am trying to create array from database objects :

I have entity "group" wich hasMany "devices", I want to create array whit all groups and for each groups the list of his devices :

```
[
{
    "group_id": “1”,
    "name": “My_group”,
    "devices_list": [1, 2, 18]
},
{
    "group_id": “2”,
    "name": “My_second_group”,
    "devices_list": [3, 24]
}
]
```

I tried several ways like this :

```
Group.all(function (err, groups) {
     var resJson = {};
     groups.forEach(function(group, index){
         group.devices(function(err, devices){
            resJson[index] = group;
            console.log(devices);
            resJson[index].devices_list = devices;

            //End of the loop
            if (index == groups.length -1){
                 send({code: 200, data: resJson});
            }
        });
    });
 });
```

**EDIT 1 :**

I tried this way too :

```
var resJson = {};
groups.forEach(function(group, index){
    group.devices(function(err, devices){
        resJson[index] = group;
        resJson[index].devices_list = [];

        devices.forEach(function(device,index2){
            resJson[index].devices_list.push(device);
        });


        //End of the loop
        if (index == groups.length -1){
            send({code: 200, data: resJson});
        }
    });
});
```

But finally, my resJson contains only empty groups (groups without device associated), the other groups are not visible. Thus my devices_list are all empty whereas the console.log(devices) display devices.

It seems that the "send" instruction is processed before the treatment of non-empty groups.

What is the rigth way to do this ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: This *shouldn't* be what is going on but I'm curious if it's the `resJson[index].devices_list = devices;` line - have you tried looping over the devices and adding them to the device list to see if that alters your return? Also, your `resJson` is an object, not an array like your goal JSON.

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I tried this, I edit my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of tracking and using an index against the length of the list perhaps you could use an `after` type of construct. I really enjoy them and they're easy to integrate and serve the perfect purpose for doing something **after** a set number of times.

First, lets define an after function you can use.

```
var after = function(amount, fn) {
  var count = 0;
  return function() {
    count += 1;
    if (count >= amount) {
      fn.apply(arguments);
    }
  };
};
```

That should work for you now, let's modify your code sample to use this.

```
var json = []; // To return, you originally wanted an array.
Group.all(function(err, groups) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle the error
  } else {
    var sendJson = after(groups.length, function(json) {
      send({code: 200, data: json});
    });
    groups.forEach(function(group) {
      group.devices(function(err, devices) {
        if (err) {
          // Handle the error...
        } else {
          group.devices_list = devices;
          json.push(group); // This part is different, using this method you'll match the JSON you gave as your "goal"
        }
        // This is outside the if/else because it needs to be called for every group
        // regardless of change. If you do not call this the exact number of times
        // that you specified it will never fire.
        sendJson(json);
    });
  }
});
```

Perhaps something like that might clear up your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help izuriel, it's working ! Effectively, the index is not reliable to do this. after function is great.